# missing data from Request

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel-5

Im new in Laravel, and I have problem in my method store like this.

this is my method in my controller.

```
    public function store(Request $request)
   {
    if($request->ajax()){

        $data = array(
               'karyawan_id'=>$request->id_kar,//here it is the problem
               'tgl_berlaku'=>$request->tgl_berlaku,
               'jumlah_gapok'=>$request->jumlah_gapok,
               'created_by'=>auth()->user()->id,
               'data_sekolah_id' => Library::sekolahSelected(),
                );
               $this->save("tb_gaji_pokok",$data);

    if($data){
    $response = $this->returnSuccess('', trans('messages.success.add'));
    return response()->json($response);
    }else{
    $response = $this->returnData('', trans('messages.error.add'));
    return response()->json($response);
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my ajax which is create the modal in view.

```
    function atur(id,a){
                        var kar_id ='<div class="col-sm-9"><input 
                        type="text" class="form-control" id="id_kar" 
                        name="id_kar" disabled> <input type="hidden" 
                        class="form-control" name="id" value="{{ $id }}"> 
                        </div>';

                        var input_gaji = '<div class="form-group"><label 
                        class="col-sm-3 control-label">Atur Gaji 
                        Pokok</label><div class="col-sm-6"><input 
                        type="text" id="jumlah_gapok" class="form-control" 
                        name="jumlah_gapok" placeholder="Jumlah"></div>
                        </div>';

                        var tanggal = '<div class="form-group"><label 
                        class="col-sm-3 control-label">Tanggal 
                        Berlaku</label><div class="col-sm-6"><div 
                        class="input-group"><input type="text" 
                        id="tgl_berlaku" class="form-control tgl_berlaku" 
                        name="tgl_berlaku" placeholder="Tanggal Berlaku">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-
                        calendar"></i></span></div></div></div>';

                        var infoModal = $('#gajipokok');
                        if(id) {
                        $.ajax({
                        url: path+'/aturgaji/'+id+'/'+a,
                        type: "GET",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success:function(data) {
                        alert(data.karyawan.nama);              
                        htmlData = '<h4>Nama karyawan  :  
                        '+data.karyawan.nama+'</h4><h4>Status  :  
                        '+data.karyawan.status_karyawan+'</h4><h4>Jabatan  :  
                        '+data.jabatan.nama_jabatan+'</h4>
                        <td>'+input_gaji+'</td><td>'+tanggal+'</td>'+kar_id;

                        infoModal.find('.modal-body').html(htmlData);
                        $('.tgl_berlaku').datepicker({
                        format: "yyyy-mm-dd",

                        todayBtn: "linked",
                        autoclose: true,
                        todayHighlight: true,
                        }).on('changeDate', function(e) {
                        $('#form').formValidation('revalidateField', 
                        'tgl_berlaku');
                        });//datepicker tgl_awal
                        $('#id_kar').val(data.karyawan.id);
                        modalGajiShow();


                        }
                        );
                         }
                         else {
                          modalGajiHide();
                          notify(0, 'Something when wrong');
                          }

                         }
```

and the problem is here :

```
    'karyawan_id'=>$request->id_kar,
```

that request return nothing, so in the database, karyawan_id's column still Null

can someone help me fix this? thank you.

Comment: your are not sending any data from request... i observed that you are sending  'id' and 'a' in url..

Comment: 'id' and 'a' are use for receive some datas from an event so a modal can be shown based on 'id' and 'a'

Comment: anyway, thanks @SurenderSinghRawat..

Comment: your id_kar input field disabled and you are sending 'id'

Comment: the problem is solve, Idk, but when i change the text input mode from disbled to enable, the $request->id_kar doesn't returning a null data anymore.

Comment: is that disabled input field the is problem?